# How to unit test code that adds a string to a bit map

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bitmap

I'm trying to unit test some code that adds a string to a bitmap. The code works fine when the app is running. But I'm having trouble writing a unit test for it.

This is the SUT:

```
public byte[] AddStringToImage(byte[] image, string caption)
{
    using(var mstream = new MemoryStream(image))
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(mstream))
    {

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            g.DrawString(caption, new Font("Tahoma", 30), Brushes.Red, 0, 0);
        }
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I hoped it might be as easy as passing a byte array and string to it. Something like so:

```
var imageContents = new byte[1000];
new Random().NextBytes(imageContents);
const string Caption = "Sold";
AddStringToImage(imageContents, Caption);
```

but it throws a **Parameter is not valid** exception on the line:

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(mstream))
```

I presume the byte array needs to be in a certain format, which makes sense.

How would I go about creating a suitable byte array in a unit test so I can pass it to the addStringToImage method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct your array out of the BITMAP header and randomize the image bytes only.
The BITMAP format is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

By the way, what you're writing is not really a unit test, it is an integration test, since it actually involves at least 2 layers: your code and the framework code that instantiates the BITMAP class.

If you want to really unit test this you need to use mocks.